# How does `sudo` search the path for executables?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, rubygems

I am using rubygems (1.3.7) with gems that require root privileges on Ubuntu 10.10. When I compare my setup to an ubuntu 9.10 with rubygems 1.3.6 installation, I see the following difference in `gem environment`:

1.3.7 / 10.10 `- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin`

1.3.6 / 09.10 `- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin`

The output is the same whether I use `sudo` or not. To fix this (I don't know why it is different in the first place), I tried to modify my path variable.

My question is, where does `sudo` look for executables? If I install a gem (using `sudo`) the executable is placed in the `/var` path obviously. I added this path to my `~/.profile` and `/etc/environment` files, but I cannot get `sudo` to execute the executables.

If I run:

- `$ gemname` it runs my tool correctly.
- `$ sudo gemname` it merely tells me `command not found`.
- `$ sudo echo $PATH` it *does* show the correct path.
- `$ sudo -i gemname` it runs correctly.
- `$ sudo sudo -V` shows that the PATH is preserved.

Does `sudo` honour `~/.profile` and/or `/etc/environment`? If so, they why can't it find my executable while the directory is shown in the `$PATH` environment variable?

I have read the documentation of `sudo`, I also search and looked through a ton of topics on stackoverflow and serverfault (for instance [How to override a PATH environment variable in sudo?](https://serverfault.com/questions/11899/how-to-succeed-a-path-environment-variable-in-sudo), but my example shows that `$PATH` contains the correct path), but they never actually show how to run a gem via `sudo`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that, in your third command, your shell expands `$PATH` before sudo gets to see it, and so the output is your shell's path, not the PATH that sudo sees. What you want is something like `sudo echo \$PATH` or `sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH'`.

Beyond that, take a look at the SECURITY NOTES section of the `sudo(8)` man page. I believe that Ubuntu builds `sudo` with the SECURE_PATH build option. Look for the "Value to override user's $PATH with" line in the output of `sudo sudo -V`.

`sudo -i` simulates an initial login, and so will read files like `.profile` (though which files it reads depends on what root's shell is). Without `-i`, it inherits the preserved environment variables from its caller's environment, with the PATH sanitation I mentioned above.

As for why the path changed in the first place, I suspect that the change was a deliberate choice on the part of the developers. See more discussion on [bugs.debian.org](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=403407).

Comment: Thanks! I missed the obvious expansion before sudo :-) I see the override of path in sudo sudo -V now, although I find that conflicting the 'Environment variables to preserve:' statement later on. I suppose I have to set the NEW path in my sudoers file to prevent the -i?

Comment: Yes, that's probably best.

Comment: `sudo echo \$PATH` just produces '$PATH' for me. but your `sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH'` does the trick. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Let's go by parts:

- gemname it runs my tool correctly.

That's ok :)

- sudo gemname it merely tells me command not found.

`gemname` is not in your `$PATH`

- sudo echo $PATH it does show the correct path.

That's a cool one: variable expansion happens before bash runs the program. So when you run this, it expands to your user `$PATH` **before** calling sudo, so the line that is passed to sudo is more like:

```
$ sudo echo "/usr/bin:/bin:"
```

- sudo -i gemname it runs correctly.

`sudo -i` runs as a login shell and honors `.profile` and/or `.login`. As by the `man` page says:

> It also initializes the environment,
>                      leaving DISPLAY and TERM unchanged, setting HOME, MAIL,
>   SHELL, USER, LOGNAME, and PATH, as
>   well as the contents of
>                      /etc/environment on Linux and AIX systems.  All other
>   environment variables are removed.

Comment: Just a quibble: `gemname` is in his `$PATH`, as otherwise the first example wouldn't work. It's not in the sanitized `$PATH` that `sudo` (without `-i`) uses.

Comment: Thanks! I assume that's the .profile of the calling user? Or root/the -u'd user?

Comment: The second option.